# "no way I'm telling you" vs "no way I tell you"

Tags: grammar

> There's no way I'm telling you about her show.
>
> There's no way I tell you about her show.

I read first sentence in a book but it sounded weird to me!
Would second sentence be considered as an alternative to first sentence?

Comment: It's the second one that sounds awkward to me, not the first.

Comment: I agree with J.R.  Idiomatically, we use the first one, not the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is alright because it's acceptable to use a gerund in a sentence when you talk about present events.

Comment: So,what about the second one?

Answer (score 1):

> There's no way I'm telling you about her show.

Idiomatic using the present tense (continuous).

---

> There's no way I **will** tell you about her show.

Idiomatic using the future tense (simple).